# Sum three specific cells without cell reference adjustment for inserted columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In this Excel worksheet, I want to always sum columns D to F, even if the current contents are moved by inserting columns.

If I use the formula `=SUM(D3:F3)`, the formula gets automatically adjusted by Excel if I insert a column.  I need the reference to columns D:F to remain unchanged.  Is there a way to do this?

[image: Excel image here]

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. The table looks like it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("D3:F3"))
```

as you insert columns around column **C**, the formula will remain the same.

Before column insert:

[image]

and after column insert:

[image]

Comment: wow, Thanks...

One more help, how to apply all the values ?

Comment: @Prakash  Just copy down the column

Comment: i tried, but same formula only applied all the cells. For example from ur sheet, copy down or dragging make all cell turned into 3